# 3-digit grouping of all numbers in an alphanumeric string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I found it not efficient to iterate through string parts split by space character and extract numeric parts and apply

```
UInt64.Parse(Regex.Match(numericPart, @"\d+").Value)
```

and the concatenating them together to form the string with numbers being grouped.

Is there a better, more efficient way to `3-digit` grouping of all numbers in an string containing other characters?

Comment: Can you show an example input and output values?

Comment: @SonerGönül e.g.: input: 'Hello 34234456 where 3334 is it?' output 'Hello 34,234,456 where 3,334 is it?'

Comment: _"3-digit grouping of all numbers"_ so if the string is `"ABC 12345 DEF"` you want a result `"123 45"`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter not if they are not seperated by an space character

Comment: @Farshid: have a look again at my comment. As a result you really want to group three consecutive digits and concat the rest at the end?

Comment: @TimSchmelter You are right. I expect to get ABC 12,345 DEF

Comment: @Farshid: so you want to replace all longs in a string with the same long but with a number-group-separator of the current culture?

Comment: @TimSchmelter for example (hello 134443 in the 33 when 88763 then) > (hello 134,443 in the 33 when 88,763 then)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to replace all longs in a string with the same long but with a number-group-separator of the current culture? .... Yes

```
string[] words = input.Split();
var newWords = words.Select(w => 
{
    long l;
    bool isLong = System.Int64.TryParse(w.Trim(), out l);
    if(isLong) 
        return l.ToString("N0");
    else
        return w;
});
string result = string.Join(" ", newWords);
```

With the input from your comment:

```
string input = "hello 134443 in the 33 when 88763 then";
```

You get the expected result:  `"hello 134,443 in the 33 when 88,763 then"`, if your current culture uses comma as number-group-separator.

Comment: This will destroy multi-space, newline and tab-spacings, but otherwise: nice as usual!

Comment: @DrKoch: yes, it will. So either it doesn't contain them or it is desired/doesn't matter if the result doesn't contain them anymore. If OP only want to split on spaces he can use `input.Split(' ')`.  But  it won't destroy multiple spaces because i haven't used `RemoveEmptyEntries`.

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure the most efficient way (CPU-wise, with just a single pass over the string) is the basic foreach loop, along these lines

```
var sb = new StringBuilder()
foreach(char c in inputString)
{
    // if c is a digit count
    // else reset counter
    // if there are three digits insert a "."
}
return sb.ToString()
```

This will produce 123.456.7

If you want 1.234.567 you'll need an additional buffer for digit-sequences

Comment: I'm looking for an efficient way

Comment: e.g. regex expressions

Comment: define _effficient_! Do you mean CPU cycles or number of characters in source code or number of minutes to understand the source code?

Comment: Instead of an additional buffer, to get 1.234.567 you can just use a reverse for-loop. The index of the for loop matches the place where the dot needs to be inserted, and the insert doesn't affect the positions of lower indices.

Answer (score 0):

I will post my regex-based example. I believe regex does not have to be too slow, especially once it is compiled and is declared with `static` and `readonly`.

```
// Declare the regex
private static readonly Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))", RegexOptions.Compiled); 
// Then, somewhere inside a method
var replacement = string.Format("$1{0}", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator);  // Get the system digit grouping separator
var strn = "Hello 34234456 where 3334 is it?"; // Just a sample string
// Somewhere (?:inside a loop)?
var res = regex.Replace(strn, replacement);
```

Output (if `,` is a system digit grouping separator):

```
Hello 34,234,456 where 3,334 is it?
```

Comment: What do you think about this approach? It is actually just 3 lines. The regex is a bit difficult to read, it means "match any digit that is followed by any number of 3-digit groups until a non-digit is found", and we replace this same digit with a digit and a digit grouping separator. But it should be fast as it is compiled and declared as a static readonly field.